# How to list down all the local temporary tables used in all stored procedures and triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2012. Looking for a single query which can list down all the local temporary tables used in the database. I have wrote this script for listing these details. Just looking whether is there an easy another method to list down all local temporary tables used in all DB objects names.

Here is script :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON    

DECLARE @cntr INT = 0
DECLARE @ObjId INT = 0
DECLARE @ObjName VARCHAR(255)

CREATE TABLE #tmpProcResultsTempTables 
(
    IdKey INT IDENTITY,
    ProcText VARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpProcResultsTempTablesOP 
(
    ObjName VARCHAR(255), 
    TableName VARCHAR(255)
)

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @ObjId = MIN(OBJECT_ID)
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE type = 'P'
      AND OBJECT_ID > @ObjId

    IF @ObjId IS NULL
        BREAK

    SELECT @ObjName = NAME
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE type = 'P'
      AND OBJECT_ID = @ObjId

    PRINT @ObjName
    PRINT @cntr

    INSERT INTO #tmpProcResultsTempTables (ProcText)
        EXEC sp_helptext @ObjName

    DELETE #tmpProcResultsTempTables
    WHERE IdKey < (SELECT IdKey
                   FROM #tmpProcResultsTempTables
                   WHERE ProcText LIKE 'CREATE PROCEDURE %')

    DELETE #tmpProcResultsTempTables
    WHERE LTRIM(ProcText) LIKE '--%'

    INSERT INTO #tmpProcResultsTempTablesOP (ObjName, TableName)
        SELECT  
            @ObjName,
            SUBSTRING(ProcText, CHARINDEX('#', ProcText), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(ProcText, CHARINDEX('#', ProcText) + 1, LEN(ProcText)))) TableName
        FROM 
            #tmpProcResultsTempTables
        WHERE 
            ProcText LIKE '% #%'
            AND ISNULL(SUBSTRING(ProcText, CHARINDEX('#', ProcText), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(ProcText, CHARINDEX('#', ProcText) + 1, LEN(ProcText)))), '') <> ''

        TRUNCATE TABLE #tmpProcResultsTempTables

        SET @cntr = @cntr + 1
    END

    DROP TABLE #tmpProcResultsTempTables

    SELECT DISTINCT ObjName
        ,Tablename
    FROM #tmpProcResultsTempTablesOP

    DROP TABLE #tmpProcResultsTempTablesOP
```

We are working on a project to bring all the Temporary tables with a standard naming convention.

Comment: T-SQL is not a good programming language, especially when it comes to string matching tasks. On the other hand, this would be almost trivial if you dumped the database as a script and used any standard tool supporting regex matches -- matching all words starting with `#` could give *some* false positives, but not many.

Comment: That's true. The results are so imperfect. It will give bad results on the string search.

Comment: Do you want functions, triggers, views in addition to SP?

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes. That is the requirement.